# Product in the Category of $L$-structures with Homomorphisms.

Tags: category-theory, model-theory

let $\scr {A}_1$, and $\scr {A}_2$ be $L$-structures. Define an L-structure $\scr A_1 \times \scr A_2$ with universe $A_1 \times A_2$, such that the natural epimorphism $\pi_i :\scr A_1 \times \scr A_2 \to \scr A_i $ for $i=1,2$ satisfy the following universal property:

given any $L$-structure $\scr D$ and homomorphisms $\phi _i : \scr D \to \scr A_i$ for $i=1,2$, there is a unique homomorphism $\psi : \scr D \to \scr A_1 \times \scr A_2 $ such that $\pi_i(\psi)=\phi_i$ for $i=1,2$

*This notion also popped up in a category theory book I stumbled upon. However, it was taken as an axiom without any further explanation.*

**Construction:**

Let $\scr A_1,A_2$ be two $L$-structures with $f_i^{\scr A_i} \in \scr A_i$.

Define $\scr A_1 \times \scr A_2$ as $\langle A_1 \times A_2, \pi_i \rangle$ including constants induced by $f_i$ and relation on each $A_i$

Define
$\pi_i: A_1 \times A_2 \to A_i$, as follows,

$\pi_i=\{(a,f(a))| a,f(a)\in \scr A_i\}$ with $i=1,2$

Will this work?

Comment: Try to see what the product looks like in familiar cases such as the theory of groups, rings, or ordered sets.

Comment: @CaptainLama I was suggested that earlier, I think I have something close to an answer. I will update the question with my work shortly.

Comment: Why did you delete the previous version of this question?

Comment: @AlexKruckman I found the same notion in another book, but it was taken as an axiom of Category theory. Also I came up with a construction (which I am not sure about) so wanted to repost for more exposure and added tag. Regards

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost Ok. You can always edit your question if you want to change the content or tags (I think your old title was much better, by the way). Deleting and reposting to increase exposure is definitely frowned upon.

Comment: @AlexKruckman sorry about that, also fixed the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've written in the construction section makes no sense to me. Most of it doesn't even parse correctly.

The task is to define an $L$-structure $\mathscr{A}_1\times \mathscr{A}_2$. You are told that the universe of this structure should be the cartesian product $A_1\times A_2$. It remains to define, for each symbol in the language, an interpretation of that symbol on $A_1\times A_2$.

You *don't* need to define $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$: the "natural epimorphisms" referred to in the question are just the projections onto each coordinate. So $\pi_1\colon A_1\times A_2\to A_1$ is defined by $\pi_1(a_1,a_2) = a_1$, and $\pi_2\colon A_1\times A_2\to A_2$ is defined by $\pi_2(a_1,a_2) = a_2$.

Ok, let's say we have a constant symbol $c$ in the language. Then we have elements $c^{\mathscr{A}_1}\in A_1$ and $c^{\mathscr{A}_2}\in A_2$. We want to interpret $c^{\mathscr{A}_1\times \mathscr{A}_2}$ as an element of $A_1\times A_2$. Which element shall we pick? There's really only one reasonable choice: $c^{\mathscr{A}_1\times \mathscr{A}_2} = (c^{\mathscr{A}_1},c^{\mathscr{A}_2})$.

Now let's say we have an $n$-ary function symbol $f$ in the language. Then we have functions $f^{\mathscr{A}_1}\colon A_1^n\to A_1$ and $f^{\mathscr{A}_2}\colon A_2^n\to A_2$. We want to interpret $f^{\mathscr{A}_1\times \mathscr{A}_2}$ as a function $(A_1\times A_2)^n\to (A_1\times A_2)$. Again, there's really only one reasonable choice: $f^{\mathscr{A}_1\times \mathscr{A}_2}((a_1,a_1'),\dots,(a_n,a_n')) = (f^{\mathscr{A}_1}(a_1,\dots,a_n),f^{\mathscr{A}_2}(a_1',\dots,a_n'))$.

Finally, let's say we have an $n$-ary relation symbol $R$ in the language. Then we have relations $R^{\mathscr{A}_1}\subseteq A_1^n$ and $R^{\mathscr{A}_2}\subseteq  A_2^n$. We want to interpret $R^{\mathscr{A}_1\times \mathscr{A}_2}$ as a subset of $(A_1\times A_2)^n$. This time it's not so obvious what to choose, but the right choice is still the most natural one: $((a_1,a_1'),\dots,(a_n,a_n'))\in R^{\mathscr{A}_1\times \mathscr{A}_2}$ if and only if $(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in R^{\mathscr{A}_1}$ *and* $(a_1',\dots,a_n')\in R^{\mathscr{A}_2}$.

The above defines the $L$-structure $\mathscr{A}_1\times \mathscr{A}_2$. Having given you the construction, I'll leave it to you to try to verify the universal property.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated.